# Does NET Standard 2.0 requires windows 10 when developing in Xamarin?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, mobile, .net-standard

I created a new proyect of a mobile app with Xamarin(Net Standard) in Visual Studio 2017

And i got this error message
[image]

I just created it and gives me this , i read over more than once that i may need Windows 10 in order to work with NET Standard 2.0, any idea if it is true?, any idea what's the problem how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: please do NOT post error messages as images

Comment: Which version of PC system is used ? Have a check with this sample whether can work in your local site :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/first-app/?pivots=win-vs2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , **.Net Standard 2.0** not necessarily **Windows10** . I think your problem maybe otherwhere .

About [Supported .NET implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/whats-new/whats-new-in-dotnet-standard?tabs=csharp#supported-net-implementations) , .NET Standard 2.0 is supported by the following .NET implementations:

- .NET Core 2.0 or later
- .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later
- Mono 5.4 or later
- Xamarin.iOS 10.14 or later
- Xamarin.Mac 3.8 or later
- Xamarin.Android 8.0 or later
- Universal Windows Platform 10.0.16299 or later

And [Windows requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements#windows-requirements) of Xamarin Forms , also not necessarily Windows 10 .Using a Windows computer for Xamarin development requires the following software/SDK versions. Check your operating system version (and confirm that you are not using an Express version of Visual Studio - if so, consider updating to a Community edition). The **Visual Studio 2019** and **Visual Studio 2017** installer includes an option to install Xamarin automatically (the Mobile development with .NET workload).

However ,  Xamarin.Forms UWP support requires **Windows 10**.

**Note** :

- Xamarin for Visual Studio supports Visual Studio 2019 or Visual Studio 2017 (Community, Professional, and Enterprise).
- To develop Xamarin.Forms apps for the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) requires Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017. Visual Studio 2019 is recommended.